# JCIFS jcifs.smb.SmbFile#renameTo dislikes special characters like '&'

Tags: java, apache-camel, jcifs

I've encounter a problem when operating on a remote Windows share with name containing '&' character using jcifs via apache-camel. The root cause of this is that apparently jcifs doesn't handle '&' character too well while renaming remote file while Windows has no problems with that.

```
public class SmbFileTest {

    @Test
    public void testAmperstand() throws Exception {
        String targetLocation = "smb://user:pass@host/share/hello&goodbye";
        SmbFile targetLocationFile = new SmbFile(targetLocation);
        if(!targetLocationFile.exists()){
            targetLocationFile.mkdirs();
        }
        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(targetLocation+"/to.tmp");
        IOUtils.write("content",smbFile.getOutputStream());
        SmbFile smbFileDest = new SmbFile(targetLocation+"/to.txt");
        smbFile.renameTo(smbFileDest);
    }
}
```

the above test fails (jcifs 1.3.17 <= camel 2.12.1)

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I could simply change the directory name but maybe someone knows a better approach. What if it would be very hard to change it?

Comment: does anyone know how I can rename an Smb-Directory? Because renaming just an SmbFile creates a new directory, but it doesnt contain the subdirectories of the original one

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the output stream `smbFile.getOutputStream()` before renaming

Comment: Yep, You've nailed it! Thanks